# Azure DevOps: Substitute variables with variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have `Azure key vault`, where in I have set of keys written

```
dev-key
stg-key
prd-key
```

Now I have downloaded the key `dev-key` in `azure DevOps pipeline`. I want to map the downloaded variable to the 'constant' variable called `'key'`, as this variable is being used in deployment yaml files(I am replacing this variable in token replace step)

Currently I am mapping this variable in pipeline variables like,

```
tenant: dev
key: $($(tenant)-key)
```

However the value is set in deployment yaml file to the key is `$(dev-key)`.
Can we substitute variables with variables in `Azure DevOps` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving of nested variables is currently not supported.

See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/479258/nested-release-variables-fail-to-be-recognized.html

An alternate solution is the following setup:

- Have a `Key Vault`per environment
- Have a `Stage` per environment
- Key names are always the same in each `Key Vault`
- Link each vault into a variable group
- Link each variable group into your pipeline and assign a `Scope`
- In each task(s) of a `Stage` access the variable as declared in the `Variable group`

With this configuration, you can re-use the same secret key in tasks and the actual values are resolved by the scope of the variable group per `Stage` as you define.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed this with assigning the scope to the variables.

```
variable     value              scope
key         $(dev-key)           dev
key         $(stg-key)           stg
key         $(prd-key)           prd
```